# How to execute random Javascript code on a web page?

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

I'm using htmlunit to test some pages and I'd like to know how can I execute some javascript code in the context of the current page. I'm aware that the docs say I'd better emulate the behavior of a user on a page, but it isn't working this way :( (I have a `div` which has an onclick property, I call its `click` method but nothing happens). So I've made some googling and tried:

```
JavaScriptEngine jse = webClient.getJavaScriptEngine();
jse.execute(page, what here?);
```

Seems like I have to instantiate the script first, but I've found no info on how to do it (right). Could someone share a code snippet showing how to make webclient instance execute the needed code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [executeJavaScript()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#executeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29) on the page, not on `webClient`.

Example:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3);
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com/ncr");
ScriptResult scriptResult = page.executeJavaScript("document.title");
System.out.println(scriptResult.getJavaScriptResult());
```

prints "Google". (I'm sure you'll have some more exciting code to put in there.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the `JavaScriptEngine` you're quoting and maybe it's not the answer you want, but this sounds like a perfect case for [**Selenium IDE**](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/).

> Selenium IDE  is a Firefox add-on that records clicks, typing, and other actions to make a test, which you can play back in the browser.

Comment: I also highly recommend Selenium RC

Answer (score 0):

In [TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/) using the HTMLUnit backend the google example is:

```
GotoURL http://www.google.com/ncr
set %Title% as evalJavaScript document.title
Notice %Title%
```